# Is there a possibility to trigger a specific column or row with myFunction on google sheets?

Tags: gsuite-addons

I have set up a function to trigger an email to my email when any change is made, so I can be notified when a maintenance request is added to the sheet. 
I want to set it up so my trigger only occurs when a certain column (in this case A) or row is changed - as I wasn't receiving notifications with on Form Submit for some reason.

Here is my code -

```
function onEdit(e){ 
var range = e.range; if (range.getColumn() === A && range.getRow() === observedCellRow) { 

sendEmail(); MailApp.sendEmail('connor@singapm.com','Email Subject','Email Message' } }
```

What else needs to be included in this code to get an email when 'A' Column is changed/added to? Please note I have no experience whatsoever in scripting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

Your `onEdit()` simple trigger should parse the event Object. The event Object for Spreadsheet has a range property. In this property is stored the information you need to cross check in order to obtain your behavior.
For example:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  // Check if range is the cell you are observing for changes
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getColumn() === observedCellColumn && range.getRow() === observedCellRow) {
      myFunction(); // This is your function that sends the email.
  }
}
```

### Reference

[event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Ok, but how do I use the myFunction and onEdit together? I am completely new to google scripting. All I want is to have my original code trigger when Column 'A' has been edited/changes, not a trigger (in this case a mail notification) every time a simple edit is made. Sorry if that doesn't really make sense but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Of course, call `myFunction` from the `onEdit` trigger when it respects your conditions. I made an edit to make myself clearer.

Comment: Please review & edit as I am still having trouble. 

function onEdit(e){
  
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getColumn() === observedCellColumn && range.getRow() === observedCellRow) {
      myFunction(); MailApp.sendEmail('connor@singapm.com','Email Subject','Email Message'
  }
}

Comment: @Connor please describe the problem you are encountering. The code you posted in your comment has a typo and the variables `observedCellColumn` and `observedCellRow` are not declared. Update the code in your question so is more visible.

Comment: Apoligies. I have updated the code in my question and the question itself. I do not understand scripting yet and would simply like a code that works for Column A changes/add on's or form submit(which seems not to work) Thanks